# Problems using opencv 3.4.16

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

**I build opencv 3.4.16 from source on Ubuntu 18.04. Then I run examples in opencv folder to check if it is installed successfully. And error occurs:**

```
(base) tianbot@charlie-miao:~/opencv-3.4.16/samples/cpp/example_cmake$ ./opencv_example
Built with OpenCV 3.4.16
No capture
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  OpenCV(3.4.16) /jiangjiajun/opencv-3.4.16/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:658: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'
```

I have checked libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config are both installed correctly.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Did you install libgtk and pkg-config before you ran configure? Try looking at the configure log to see whether it detected libgtk installed. There might be an option to explicitly use gtk.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to integrate fastdeploy library into ORB_SLAM3 system. And I have installed the latest version of fastdeploy which have the opencv 3.4.16 different on my own opencv 3.2.0. When I remake the whole project I ran into this error. It seems the error occours due to the conflict between 2 different versions of opencv.

Comment: Could anyone told me how to set the fastdeploy to use my own opencv 3.2.0 or told me which version of fastdeploy are using opencv 3.2.0 so that i can just reinstalled that version.